# Do Dpkg and apt-get install dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I've been wondering, is there a way to tell `dpkg` or `apt-get` that when I want to install a package also install all the dependencies it requires? I installed a package using `dpkg` but it complained about some dependency issues so I had to manually search one by one, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: dpkg does not handle dependencies, it's a low level package management tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dependencies should be installed by default with apt-get. You might also want to read the answers for this question: [Installing suggested/recommended packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages).

Comment: And if it doesn't?! I run this command: "apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop, And it says The foloowing packages have unmet dependencies: checkbox-qt, eog,gedit,....... too many packages.

Answer (score 12):

apt-get or aptitude will install all the dependencies of a package. According to apt-get man page

> All packages required by the
>   package(s) specified for installation
>   will also be retrieved and installed.

Even if you want to install a package from source you can install its build dependencies using apt-get. Use **apt-get build-dep** for that purpose. Again from apt-get man page:

> **build-dep** causes apt-get to
>   install/remove packages in an attempt
>   to satisfy the build dependencies for
>   a source package.

For example if you want to compile **gcc** you will need all the build dependencies for successfully compiling gcc. So you use `sudo apt-get build-dep gcc`. This will install  all the packages required to build **gcc** from source.

Answer (score 8):

If after using `dpkg` to install a package it tells you that there are missing dependencies, you can run `apt-get -f install` to install any missing dependencies on your system.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a tool that will install a downloaded (ie. non-repository based) package including dependencies, look at [gdebi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gdebi-core) (the GTK UI) or [gedebi-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gdebi-core) (the command line tool).