# How to use apt-get install with suggested packages?

Tags: 11.10, apt

I read this related link [Installing suggested/recommended packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages)

But my system(11.10) doesn't install suggested packages by default.
Was there a change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read carefully the accepted answer in the question you link, you can see that this is the default behavior.

To install suggested packages you should add this to the command line:

```
-o APT::Install-Suggests="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

When I do a command line `apt-get install foo`, if the list of suggested packages looks interesting, I abort the command, and append the suggested packages to my command line. The way I understand it, "Suggested packages" are just that - suggestions. Maybe they'll help users of package `foo`, maybe not. I want to decide for my self, and you can decide for yourself. Our mutual mileages may vary.