# Differences between "apache"'s installations

Tags: installation, apt, apache2

Are there any differences between installing **Apache httpd** using `sudo apt-get install apache2` (as the guide of Ubuntu says - https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html
) or following the steps on the Apache documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html#overview)?

I tried both ways; in the first case (using `apt-get`) the server seems to work - I open a browser page and I got it. In the second case I need other packages (*apr*, *apr-util* and *pcre*) and so I abandoned the attempt.

Comment: I doubt if that's what you want, but have you tried XAMPP?

Comment: Thank you. I had never heard before, but reading the official site it seems a good choice. However I'd like to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Use the LAMP install from command `tasksel` and you will get all you want plus it will be already configured for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when you use apt-get (default package manager for Ubuntu), it automatically installs the dependencies. But when installing manually (using `./configure`, `make` and `make install`), you'll have to make sure that the dependencies are already installed for the program to work. Otherwise, you'll have to manually install the required dependencies as well.

You can refer the answer to this question for further details:
[Installing suggested/recommended packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages)