# How to always install suggested packages with apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management

I was reading in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages?answertab=active#tab-top) on how to install suggested packages.

I get how to do it with `apt-get install whatever-package-name --install-suggests`. 
But I read that you could make a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` and put in the line `APT::Install-Suggests "true"`. But what I don't understand is what type of file to make.

*P.S. If I am totally off base or you don't understand what I am trying to say just let me know. I'm still a bit nooby.*

Comment: Although you can do this, I would not recommend it.  Some packages have a huge amount of suggests, loading far more than you think they will.  For example, `sudo apt-get install tuxguitar` installs a simple program for guitar tabs.  `sudo apt-get install tuxguitar --install-suggests` downloads and installs about 2 GB worth of stuff...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any type for that file.

```sh
echo 'APT::Install-Suggests "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom
```