# Unwanted Applications Installed after Installing Desktop Environments on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, unity, kubuntu, xubuntu, xfce

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I recently installed additional desktop environments on my Ubuntu system using the following commands:

arduino

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop # for KDE
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop # for Xfce
```

Unfortunately, these commands installed some applications that I don't need or want, such as Xterm and Elisa. I would like to remove these applications to free up disk space and keep my system clean.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to uninstall these unwanted applications. Specifically, I would like to know the steps to remove Xterm and Elisa completely from my Ubuntu system.

Comment: `sudo apt purge` [package name]

Comment: Skipping recommended packages might help. See [Installing suggested/recommended packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages)

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not an ubuntu guru, but my rule of thumb is to never test desktop environments on directly on my machine for this exact reason, because purging them is too hard.

Comment: You've not provided release details; as given packages are built/packaged for a specific release, there can be *depends* rules that influence what's best where multiple desktops are installed. As you know your release, I suggest you explore the answers yourself, as we weren't provided what I consider essential release details for multi-desktop questions.  FYI:  I send @Kulfy suggestion on not installing recommends.. it's how Lubuntu suggest getting a minimal install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages you installed are metapackages to install desktop environments. This means that they install a list of packages deemed necessary or recommended for the desktop environment you are installing. If you install multiple desktop environments, redundant packages may be installed, e.g. different text editors, mail clients, etc.

If applications are installed that you do not want, remove them. Use the application "Ubuntu Software", tab "Installed", for that. End user software as listed under the heading "Applications". These can be safely removed. Under that, you will see a section "System Applications". Leave these alone unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for help, as you suggested, I followed your instructions and the problem has been resolved.